# How to track duplicates in XML list using XQuery?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have the below XML structure :

```
<Books>
    <Book>
        <ItemReference>
            <ClassificationCode listID="Name">Book1</ClassificationCode>
            <ClassificationCode listID="Property2"/>
            <ClassificationCode listID="Property3"/>
        </ItemReference>
    </Book>

    <Book>
        <ItemReference>
            <ClassificationCode listID="Name">Book2</ClassificationCode>
            <ClassificationCode listID="Property2"/>
            <ClassificationCode listID="Property3"/>
        </ItemReference>
    </Book>

    <Book>
        <ItemReference>
            <ClassificationCode listID="Name">Book1</ClassificationCode>
            <ClassificationCode listID="Property2"/>
            <ClassificationCode listID="Property3"/>
        </ItemReference>
    </Book>

    <Book>
        <ItemReference>
            <ClassificationCode listID="Name">Book4</ClassificationCode>
            <ClassificationCode listID="Property2"/>
            <ClassificationCode listID="Property3"/>
        </ItemReference>
    </Book>
</Books>
```

What is the proper way to form my for loop using XQuery,in order to create a validation rule to return as log a validation error when it founds duplicates in `ClassificationCode[@listID = 'Name']/text()` where the `/text() = ('Book1', 'Book4')`? That means i don't want to use the same validation for Book2. my problem is that i care about particular items if they will be double or not. To give more details my Validation XQuery looks like this :

```
    declare function local:BooksValidation (
    $books as element()*, 

    {

    for $book in $books 
        let $ItemRef := $book/ItemReference

    return (
        if (fn:exists($ItemRef)) then ()
        else 
            local:Issue($error, "No Items found", $currentPath)
            )
    }

    declare function local:Issue (
        $errorCode as xs:string, 
        $message as xs:string, 
        $xpath as xs:string) as xs:string* 
    {   
        concat($errorCode, ': ', $message, ' (XPath : ',  $xpath, ')')
    };
```

and i want to include in this for-loop an exact same if-statement that will check if there are double items

Comment: It is not clear which result you are looking for. I don't see any duplicates based on `ClassificationCode[@listID = 'Name'][. = ('Book1', 'Book4')]` as the first item has `ClassificationCode listID="FulfillmentItemCode"`. So please explain in more detail what you are looking for and how the usual XQuery tools with grouping and/or distinct-values don't help.

Comment: The one with the "FulfillmentItemCode" was a mistake i fixed it. To be specific i want based on that property to check if ````ClassificationCode[@listID = 'Name']/text() = ('Book1', 'Book4') < 2 then () else local:log("Double Items")````` but i can't figure out the fn: that would help to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query for finding duplicate ' element values:

```
        let $text :=fn:distinct-values($xml/Book/ItemReference/ClassificationCode[@listID = "Name"]/text())
         for $each in $text
             let $seq := if(count($xml//ClassificationCode[@listID = "Name"]/text()[. = $each]) > 1)
                 then(concat($each, " Values are duplicate"))
                 else()
        return $seq
```

Comment: i edited my problem in order to make it more specific...the above will work but for every item

Answer (score 0):

To identify duplicates in XQuery (3 and later) you use the `group by` clause of a FLOWR expression to group the items and the `where` clause to check whether the grouping has found more than one item in a group:

```
declare variable $names as xs:string* external := ('Book1', 'Book4');

for $name in //ClassificationCode[@listID = 'Name'][. = $names]
group by $v := $name
where tail($name)
return 'duplicates for ' || $v
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8q

With XQuery 1 you can use

```
declare variable $names as xs:string* external := ('Book1', 'Book4');

let $names := //ClassificationCode[@listID = 'Name'][. = $names],
    $keys := distinct-values($names)
for $key in $keys
where $names[. = $key][2]
return concat('duplicates for ', $key)
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8q/1

Comment: unfortunately it's XQuery 1.0

Comment: @pavloskkr, I rewrote that using `distinct-values` instead of `group  by`.